# Save changes made to shiny data Table while using the App

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny App wherein i have a data table which contains various select inputs and checkbox inputs, the user can select the values in the cell using the select inputs and check boxes,is there a way i can store this data after the user has made all the selections.

I have a data frame to which i have added 3 new columns with selectinputs and checkboxes for each cells. The user can select the values using them.

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

observeEvent(input$datafile_1,{

mapping_file <<- read.csv(input$datafile_1$datapath,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({data.table(mapping_file)},
    options = list(
      dom='t',
      ordering=F,
      lengthChange = TRUE,
      pageLength=20,
      rownames= FALSE,
      initComplete = JS(
        "function(settings, json) {",
        "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#00338d', 'color': '#fff'});",
        "}"),
      autowidth = TRUE
),rownames= FALSE)

DF <- data.frame(Fields = colnames(df_master_file),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# helper function for making checkbox
shinyInput = function(FUN, len, id, ...) { 
  inputs = character(len) 
  for (i in seq_len(len)) { 
    inputs[i] = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...)) 
  } 
  inputs 
}

output$mytable2 = DT::renderDataTable({
  data.frame(DF,Mapping=shinyInput(selectInput,nrow(DF),"mapping_",
                                   choices=c("",colnames(mapping_file)),width="200px"),
                Filter=shinyInput(checkboxInput,nrow(DF),"filter_",
                                  width="50px"),
                Color=shinyInput(checkboxInput,nrow(DF),"color_",
                               width="50px")
             )
}, selection='none',server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, options = list( 
  dom = 't',
  paging=TRUE,
  preDrawCallback = JS('function() { 
  Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'), 
  drawCallback = JS('function() { 
  Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '),
  ordering=F,
  lengthChange = TRUE,
  pageLength=37,
  rownames= FALSE,
  initComplete = JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#00338d', 'color': '#fff'});",
    "}")
),rownames= FALSE )

})
```

I want to save the data once the user has made the selections on the data table so that i could be used further for analysis.

Comment: Post you code and I might help you.

Comment: I have added the code. Let me know if you need any help understanding it. Thanks

Comment: One way to do it would be to reactively create a list() of all the objects/values you need to save (e.g. inside an observeEvent on all the inputs you need to save), then save it to the app folder and check for the file when the app is opened. I've used this approach to give different users their own settings of an app, worked well enough in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something you want, but I am not 100% sure.

```
bookmarkButton()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```

These two functions allow you to store the "state" of an App, which allows you to share the selection with other users for later analysis.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         bookmarkButton()
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, enableBookmarking = "url")
```